# How to MATCH nodes with with more than 1 of a specified relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find all Datum nodes in Neo4j where there is more than 1 of the GOLDSOURCEFEED relationships pointing to it. And I don't care what type of node has the relationship. Here's the base query just so you can see the node variables etc.

```
MATCH (p:Datum)<-[:GOLDSOURCEFEED]-()
WHERE exists ( (p:Datum)<-[:GOLDSOURCEFEED]-() )
RETURN p.name
```

Obviously when I put in the list above, I get all of the Datum nodes that have a GOLDSOURCEFEED relationship, I want to refine that to only list where there's more than one GOLDSOURCEFEED relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an efficient degreeness check:

```
MATCH (p: Datum)
WHERE SIZE((p)<-[:GOLDSOURCEFEED]-()) > 1 
RETURN p.name;
```

A degreeness check simply uses data already available for each node, and does not require actually getting the paths. It is possible to perform a degreeness check when you do not care about the node on the opposite end of the relationship or any relationship properties.

[UPDATE]

Starting with neo4j 5.0, you can use a [COUNT subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/#count-subqueries) to do a degreeness check. For example:

```
MATCH (p: Datum)
WHERE COUNT{ (p)<-[:GOLDSOURCEFEED]-() } > 1 
RETURN p.name;
```

As above, this will get the degree for `p` without hitting the DB to if the pattern in the `COUNT` subquery leaves the other end of the relationship unspecified and does not specify any relationship properties.

Comment: Thank you! Both of these answers worked and gave me the same results. I marked this one correct though because the syntax was a little shorter and I understood it a tiny bit better. Thanks both

Comment: And it is also faster, but you may not notice if you don't have much data.

Answer (score 0):

I would count the number of relationships as count(r) then put this as a condition to filter more than 1 GOLDSOURCEFEED.

```
MATCH (p: Datum) <- [r: GOLDSOURCEFEED] - ()  
WITH p,  count(r) as cnt 
WHERE cnt > 1 
RETURN p.name;
```