# UNWIND statement in a Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have these nodes:

1. `user{user_id}: users`
2. `thread{thread_id, post_date} : posts`
3. `tag_id{tag_id}: the tag of the post`

And these relationships:

1. `(user) - [: FOLLOWED] -> (tag)` // the user follows the tag
2. `(thread) - [: BELONG_TO] -> (tag)` // the post belongs to tag
3. `(user) - [: READ] -> (thread)` // user reads the post

Now I want to query for each tag that user follows 5 posts that user has not read. I wrote cypher as follows:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:FOLLOWED]->(t:Tag)
WHERE u.id = 39792
WITH collect(t) as tLists
UNWIND tLists as t
MERGE (u:User)-[:FOLLOWED]->(t:Tag)<-[:BELONG_TO]-(th:Thread)<-[r:READ]-()
WHERE not (u)-[:READ]->(th)
RETURN u.id, th.id, t.id, duration.inDays(datetime(), datetime({ epochmillis: apoc.date.parse(th.post_date)})).days as time, count(r) as count_view
ORDER BY time DESC, count_view DESC
LIMIT 5
```

But it doesn't work. Help me

Comment: Do the nodes and relationships already exist? If so, you need to stop using  `MERGE`. In any case, the `MERGE`, as written, is doing a lot of damage (creating empty nodes and relationships that should not exist). And other tweaks are needed, but first we need to know if you really need this query to (potentially) create new nodes and relationships, or if you just need to read the existing data.

Comment: Well I just want to vertical the existing data. Hope you help me. @cybersam
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Do not* use [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) if you do not intend to write to the DB. (And if you do want to write to the DB, you *must* learn how to use `MERGE` properly to avoid unwanted results.)
2. *Do not* use [aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) (like `COUNT`) unless you have read the documentation and understand how to use them. In particular, you must understand what "grouping keys" are and how they affect the behavior of aggregating functions.
3. You should learn how [degreeness checks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55925975/974731) can efficiently count certain relationship patterns.

This query may work for you:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:FOLLOWED]->(t:Tag)<-[:BELONG_TO]->(th)
WHERE u.id = 39792 AND NOT EXISTS((u)-[:READ]->(th))
RETURN u.id, th.id, t.id,
  duration.inDays(datetime(), datetime({ epochmillis: apoc.date.parse(th.post_date)})).days AS days,
  SIZE((th)<-[:READ]-()) as count_view
ORDER BY days DESC, count_view DESC
LIMIT 5
```

[UPDATE]

Here is one way to get the 5 newest threads with the most views, per tag followed by the user, that the user has not yet read:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:FOLLOWED]->(t:Tag)<-[:BELONG_TO]->(th)
WHERE u.id = 39792 AND NOT EXISTS((u)-[:READ]->(th))
WITH t.id AS tagId, th.id AS threadId
ORDER BY apoc.date.parse(th.post_date) DESC, SIZE((th)<-[:READ]-()) DESC
RETURN tagId, COLLECT(threadId)[..5] AS threads
```

Comment: thank you very much @cybersam. 
I apologize if I have not stated the question clearly. But I want to get each tag that the user follows 5 posts that the user has not read
It has the form:
tag_id = 1, thread_id = {1,2,3,4,5}
tag_id = 2, thread_id = {5,6,7,8,9}
...
I look forward to your help