# Counting IN and OUT relations to a Node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, redisgraph

I'm using this query to count IN and OUT relations to a node :

```
    match (a)-[]->(b)
    where b.val = 11
    return count(a.val) as n
    union
    match (b)-[]->(c)
    where b.val = 11
    return count(c.val) as n
```

Is this a good way of doing it, seem too cumbersome to me. Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2):

*First of all, you would normally want to specify the appropriate node labels in your patterns so that the system would not be forced to scan every node. And you may also want to add an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/).*

[Degreeness checks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55925975/974731) are very fast because they do not actually need to traverse any relationships or aggregate anything:

```
MATCH (a:Foo)
WHERE a.val = 11
RETURN SIZE((a)<--()) AS inCount, SIZE((a)-->()) AS outCount
```